# Not recognizing my Nvidia RTX 2060 for optiX

Tags: linux

I am using Debian Linux Buster 10  with a Nvidia RTX 2060 card. I have included back ports which are non-free and I have the driver version Nvidia 440.82 drm installed. I am using the Blender version 2.83. The card is recognized, with the exception of optiX. I was under the impression that this driver supported this function.

Answer (score 2):

So after further study linux needs a package called libnvoptix1. This is a linked library that blender needs to run optiX once I installed this it recognized and worked.