# RTX 2080 graphics card is not recognized as Optix compatible on Debian 10

Tags: linux

I have the same issue as [Timothy Tinsman](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182529/not-recognizing-my-nvidia-rtx-2060-for-optix) on Debian 10 up to date: Blender 2.83 / 2.83.5 and 2.90 don't recognize my RTX 2080 graphics card as compatible with Optix.

[image]

CUDA, on the other hand, is functional.

The NVidia driver installed is the one offered by Debian in the non-free repository: **418.152.00 stable**.
As suggested by Timothy Tinsman [and in this post on blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-2-83-2-82a-linux-nvidia-rtx-2060-super-no-optix/1217626/15), I checked the packages **libnvoptix1**, **libnvidia-rtcore** and **libnvidia-cbl**. They're all installed.

Another leads?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I switched the NVidia drivers to 440.100 (from the backports repository) and Optix now seems to work.

Comment: Now it seems to work also for RTX Titan and Quadro 2000 on NVIDIA-SMI 510.85.02    Driver Version: 510.85.02    CUDA Version: 11.6 driver (debian testing, kernel 6.0.0-4-amd64). Single install of libnvoptix1 package solved the same issue in Blender 3.5.0 alpha.